Html text editor isn't showing on vscode
I can't write the code in VScode. I tried to uninstall and restart again but didn't work.

I want to write the code for html but i can't be able to type even a single line of code in VScode. It's just showing file name.

Do you have any extensions enabled? If so, disable them all
